# How to appear/ disappear UITableview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am working video player.. I am using `MPMediaplayer` framework…
In video player below i am displaying one UIView, in this view i am displaying current video details like Video name and video description and video starting time and ending time… Those are details are displayed in `UITableview`.
The tableview adding to this `uiview`..Those are all things are done.
The `uiview` beside i put one button.. if i click the button then automatically appear `uiview`. if i click again the uiview disappear..this is also done.

now   i am integrating animation for uiview like fade out(means if i click button appear uiview, after 10 seconds automatically disappear the uiview… )..that is my main requirement.. This is also done..

But problem is for example user scroll the uiview (video player details in tableview to scroll the tableview up and down) after 10 seconds automatically disappear. if user scroll the  video player details i don’t want to disappear my tableview… but my problem if user scroll the video player details it is automatically disappear after 10 seconds..

so plz help me any body..How to handle this thing…My requirement is if user scroll the  video player details i don’t want to disappear my tableview…

```
- (IBAction)InfoVisibleAction:(id)sender

{

    if(UIView.hidden==NO)

    {

        UIView.hidden=YES;

        ScheduleImageView.hidden=YES;

        tableView.hidden=YES;

        timeLabel1.hidden=YES;

    }

    else

    {

        UIView.hidden=NO;

        ScheduleImageView.hidden=NO;

        tableView.hidden=NO;

        timeLabel1.hidden=NO;

        [self performSelector:@selector(infoHiddenAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];

    }

}

- (IBAction)infoHiddenAction:(id)sender

{

    if(UIView.hidden==NO)

    {

        UIView.hidden=YES;

        ScheduleImageView.hidden=YES;

        tableView.hidden=YES;

        timeLabel1.hidden=YES;

    }

}

- (IBAction)infoHiddenAction:(id)sender

{

    if(UIView.hidden==NO)

    {

        SupportedView.hidden=YES;

        ScheduleImageView.hidden=YES;

        tableView.hidden=YES;

        timeLabel1.hidden=YES;

    }

}



-(void)viewDidLoad

{

    tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 550, 130)];

    tableView.delegate=self;

    tableView.dataSource=self;

    tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    tableView.scrollEnabled=YES;

    tableView.separatorColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [UIView addSubview:tableView];

}
```

Comment: can you show the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method code?

Comment: ha yes Ahmed.my requirement is if user scroll the uitableview i dont want to disappear UIView after 10 seconds.

Comment: After completion of tableview scrolling then i need to disappear(after 10 seconds)

Comment: ok where have you written the hiding or displaying code?

Answer (score 0):

The following should help

**In Your class:**

```
@implementation <YourClass> {
NSTimer* hideTimer;
}
```

**Inside (IBAction)InfoVisibleAction:(id)sender**

Instead of

```
[self performSelector:@selector(infoHiddenAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
```

Use

```
[hideTimer invalidate], hideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(infoHiddenAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

**Implement scrollViewDidScroll**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

[hideTimer invalidate], hideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(infoHiddenAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
```

**Inside (IBAction)infoHiddenAction:(id)sender**

Add

```
[hideTimer invalidate];
```

Comment: Fahad, i tried your code. But it does not work for me... plz help me bro

Comment: Have you added <UITableviewDelegate> to your class?

It should go like @implementation yourclassname <UITableViewDelegate> {
NSTimer* hideTimer;
}

Comment: yaaa. have u stack overflow chat account.. if u have stack overflow chat account plz come to chat